# Nuances of meaning between "gesucht werden" and "gesucht sein"

Tags: meaning

> (1): Ein Luftgitarrenspieler ***wird gesucht***?
>
> vs (2): Ein Luftgitarrenspieler ***ist gesucht***?

I wonder if the 1st construction with *werden* means:

> Someone is looking for an air guitarist (perhaps, in order to have him strut his stuff at a party),

whereas the 2nd construction with *sein* means:

> Air guitarists in general are currently in high demand and sought after.

If so, should the 2nd sentence be converted into a plural structure?

Comment: Use your preferred search engine to search for "Zustandspassiv" and "Vorgangspassiv".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antwort auf Frage 1: Ja, du hast den Unterschied richtig erfasst. *Jemand/etwas ist gesucht* bedeutet, dass für diesen jemanden/dieses etwas eine erhöhte Nachfrage besteht.

Antwort auf Frage 2: Ja, der Satz wäre in den meisten typischen Anwendungsfällen besser formuliert im Plural:

> Luftgitarrenspieler sind gesucht.

oder auch

> Luftgitarrenspieler sind gefragt.

Jedoch könnte man möglicherweise auch für den Satz "*Ein Luftgitarrenspieler ist gesucht*" zur Not noch irgendeinen praktischen Kontext an den Haaren herbeiziehen.